# i am unable to extract an object from a list? i get a null value when i try to store it another object

Tags: android, android-listview

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Container> result) {
            if (exception != null) {
                showAlert("Error", exception.getMessage());
            }
            ArrayList<Container> containerList = result;
            containerNames = new String[containerList.size()];
            containers = new Container[containerList.size()];
            SharedPreferences myprefs = getSharedPreferences("myCustomSharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
            String containerName = myprefs.getString("name", null).trim();
            if (containerList != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < containerList.size(); i++) {
                    Container container = containerList.get(i);
                    containers[i] = container;
                    containerNames[i] = container.getName().trim();
                    if(containerNames[i].equals(containerName))
                    {
                        abcd = containerList.get(i);
                        Log.d("value of abcd", abcd.getName());
                    }

                }
            }
            //abcd = containers[2];
            //setContainerList();
            loading = false;
            new LoadCDNContainersTask().execute((Void[]) null);
        }

    }
```

The `Log.d` doesnt work as no value gets printed in the logcat
I think there might be a problem because the content inside the if statement might not be accessed

Comment: you should trace the entering method. You will know the value of exception. And by the way, there is also a debugger in java. ;)

Comment: Have you checked that the value of `containerName` isn't `null`?

Comment: @TedHopp yes i checked that it isnt null.

Comment: Did you check for case sensitivity ?

Comment: @Eden i did but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem with these 2 lines right off the bat.

```
    containerNames = new String[containerList.size()];
    containers = new Container[containerList.size()];
```

They should have type specifications String[] and Container[] respectively. I also don't see the point of containerList considering result is passed in and you can access it.